# What's the use of touching dead enemies in Valkyria Chronicles?

Tags: valkyria-chronicles

If one of my units fall in battle and the enemy reaches it before I can, it will die for good and I can't save it anymore. I can also touch enemy units to make them despawn but I don't know why I should do this - It seems there is no enemy medic.

Do I gain any advantage by reaching fallen enemies?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the Japanese version, when you downed an enemy Ace you had to loot the body to collect their unique weapons.  This looting mechanic was dropped for the US version.